# how to deploy angular 5 with asp.net mvc structure on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, angular5

i have project with asp.net mvc and webApi i added angular 5 in it using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbHSTJBhJ44)

method. this works fine on localhost but when i deploy it on azure all other mvc view are working fine but the index(angular page) is not working giving these errors

[image: browser console]

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i successfully deployed on azure by adding(include to project) shim , system , zone folder then published it works well for me